Running Vue + Vite SPA on Android WebView API 29: Issue with Loading ESM Modules from Local Storage
I'm trying to run a Vue + Vite + TypeScript project as a production-ready SPA on Android WebView (API 29) by loading it from an SD card. However, I've encountered an issue where the WebView seems unable to load ESM-based JavaScript files when they're stored locally. I’m using the default Vue build setup, but it looks like the WebView can't handle type="module" scripts in this environment.
It seems that file:// protocol limitations in WebView prevent it from correctly loading ESM modules. Unfortunately, running an HTTP server on the device is not an option in my case.
Is this an inherent limitation of Android WebView with local ESM files and file:// protocol, or am I missing something in the setup? What would be the recommended approach to make this work? If possible, could you provide any examples or a GitHub project reference that demonstrates how to achieve this?
Thank you!
